# Uglify javascript between <script> tags

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs, page-load-time, uglifyjs2

I'm making a website which is divided in 2 pages (for reducing page-load time):

- `structure.html` contains an empty body and a tiny piece of boot-up javascript which will load `content.html` into body (until then it shows a *loading* indicator)
- `content.html` is the actual page content (heavyweight)

The boot-up javascript (which is embedded in the `structure.html` page) works fine, but it's still ~100 lines. **I'm wondering if I can minify the script embedded in html page using uglifyjs** to further reduce the page size (e.g. it'd output the same html page containing minified script).

I've tried to input my `structure.html` directly in uglifyjs but it spills an error:

```
Parse error at structure.html:1,0
Unexpected token: operator (<)
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:189:18)
    at js_error (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:197:11)
    at croak (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:657:9)
    at token_error (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:665:9)
    at unexpected (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:671:9)
    at expr_atom (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1167:9)
    at maybe_unary (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1328:19)
    at expr_ops (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1363:24)
    at maybe_conditional (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1368:20)
    at maybe_assign (C:\Users\Mihir Gokani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\parse.js:1392:20)
```

The best I can do at this time is minify that piece of code separately and copy in my `structure.html` page. Since I'm still enhancing that boot-up script, I'd like reduce the manual work.

Comment: Try sticking the javascript in an uglifier without the script tags (and other HTML), works so much better

Comment: Yes, but my script is in embedded in the html page. And I want to reduce efforts of *separating-minifying-merging* loop while it's still in development phase.

Comment: Sure you can, but you have to run something that does that automatically on the serverside, and you didn't tell us what server you're using or how you intend to this. The point is still the same, right now the script tags are being parsed, but you have to make sure they aren't part of what the uglifier receives.

Comment: Let's say I'll just fire up uglifyjs from cli. (no server in the picture; just plain old html file having some meta tags, the boot-up script, and body having *"loading..."* text - no content)

Comment: Yes, the script tags are getting parsed. But is there a way like a flag in uglify or some other way to just pipe javascript between <script> tags to uglify and put the results back in place?

Comment: I have no idea, is this in node.js? How are you using the uglify script, did you consider grunt, gulp or whatever they are called

Comment: Well, it ought to be in node.js. I'm using uglifyjs2 from command line. I've just followed the setup instructions as mentioned in their README https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Comment: I'm also open to grunt, gulp or whatever they are called if they can be used to achieve my purpose :)

Comment: Hey, has anyone found a solution to this?